# What all do we need to change while upgrading from Bing Maps v7 to v8?

Tags: bing-maps

I have changed the URL as per the guideline document given. But that's not enough I guess. I am getting some errors related to very widely used constructors such as Microsoft.maps.point.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Microsoft.Maps.moduleLoaded is not a function
    at PointBasedClustering.js:455
scripts.js:1411 Uncaught TypeError: Microsoft.Maps.Point is not a constructor
    at scripts.js:1411
    at scripts.js:2179
```

I haven't changed any sequence of files. Only on replacing this particular URL results in all these errors. I searched a round a lot but due to very less community support I was unable to find any discussion about this.

Comment: Just FYI:
    var centerOffsetPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-80, 0);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is trying to access the namespace before it is available. Ensure that you only use the Microsoft namespace inside of your map load function. I also recommend calling your map load function by adding the callback parameter t the map script URL and specifying your callback function name there. The V8 control loads asynchronously which allows your page to load faster, but this also means that it is much easier for your code to try and access the Microsoft.Maps namespace before it is available.

Also ensure that you are not just changing the version number in the map script URL as that won't work. V8 uses a completely different URL. Take a look at some of the samples: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Yes. I have changed it to the right URL as per their guide of migration.

Comment: Are you loading the point based clustering module via a script tag or using the Microsoft.Maps.loadModule function in the map load function?